# Code examples using xcode and updating information in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, xcode

I am trying to make life a little easier for several coworkers and of course ME!.  We need to update a database that controls our invoicing function.  This database is housed in SQL Server 2008 R2.  I need to provide users with a way (based on their function) to enter information affecting the invoice.  For example, John has customer interaction and sends them a pdf of a document on Monday.  We need to capture that John sent Customer A a pdf on Monday and it was associated with Project 123.  Simultaneously, Ann is color correcting a piece for Customer A but on Project 126.  I have over 50 people working in various areas who may or may not need to enter information.  My hope is to make the application generic enough that the user simply selects from drop downs tied back to the original database.

The majority of the users (80%) use Mac OS.  I have donwloaded XCode and I was hoping to use this to create the application that will update the backend database.

I am new to creating this type of application.  I have done this with VB and VBA but do not have access to those tools here.  So if there is another tact that I should take, I am more than willing to rethink my approach.

Key points are that I need to draw information from and update a SQL 2008 database.  Second, I cannot use something like Excel as a front end, since I will have multiple users accessing information simultaneously.

Comment: Why not a web application ? You could even use VB.NET to develop the backend if you are familiar with VB. it would be a lot easier than learning Objective-C, and could be better because your ObjC program would only cover 80% of the users (as you mentionned)

Answer (score 2):

You're unlikely to find many examples of connecting a Mac app directly to SQL Server, because that's a rare combination. Macs, unlike Windows PCs, aren't often used in an enterprise setting, so the software ecosystem to support enterprise development is much weaker.

If you're feeling brave, there are vendors out there that sell ODBC drivers for Mac OS X, some of which connect to SQL Server. So your problem becomes finding Mac ODBC examples, which is IMHO an easier problem. Google "mac os x odbc drivers". I have not tried any of them, so I can't speak to their quality.

This is going to be a lot of work, especially since you're new to the platform. You might want to consider exposing the database as an OData source (the name of the server-side technology is "WCF Data Services"). There are OData client-side librarires for the Mac. Google "mac os x odata". This approach completely bypasses the business of ODBC drivers, at the cost of some server-side development.